# How do I combine multiple image into a single image (not overlapping but sorted into the space) programmatically

Tags: sorting, image-processing

[image]

How do I do something similiar to the above photo programmatically, say using Python, JavaScript, PIL, ImageMagick, etc? Also is there a term for such an effect which would help me google it?

Comment: In theory. it's not that difficult. You could just work out the area of the canvas, the area of each image and then place the images in the order you would like them to appear. You could  optimise the layout so that the images would occupy as little or as much of the canvas as possible. You could use graph theory for that. See the canvas as your grid and the individual images as nodes within the graph. Use the area of an image as your node value. Then try to find the path with the shortest distance. I hope it makes sense...

Comment: Have a look here... http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/